# openLDAP works for v2.4 but v2.6 returns: Invalid syntax (21) additional info: objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap, hpc

I have been facing this problem for a few days by now, and I would like to preface this by stating that this is the first time I have ever used ldap. So after debugging a bit around the error I have discovered that one of the processes that fails (and subsequently gets ignored) was the ldapadd command running to add the local_scheme. After looking into that I discovered that the problem resides within the password policy, and now I hit a brick wall.

Even because I know for a fact that this command works fine with openldap 2.4 but not with openldap 2.6. I will leave the pwdpolicy here along with the error the ldap add command invokes.
pwdPolicy:

```
dn: cn=pwdDefaultPolicy,ou=Policies,dc=local
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
cn: pwdDefaultPolicy
sn: pwdDefaultPolicy
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdCheckQuality: 1
pwdMinAge: 0
pwdMaxAge: 0
pwdMinLength: 8
pwdInHistory: 2
pwdMaxFailure: 3
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdLockout: FALSE
pwdLockoutDuration: 0
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdExpireWarning: 0
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdMustChange: FALSE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
```

Error returned:

```
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

And thank you all in advance!

EDIT: I would like to add that I tried removing each objectClass individually or even altogether. That did not lead to any place fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

Your OpenLDAP service configuration needs to have the `ppolicy` overlay module loaded.

In OpenLDAP 2.4, the password policy attributes and the respective object classes were defined in a statically loaded schema (ppolicy.schema), meaning that a pwdPolicy entry could be created independently from the module as long as the schema definition was in place (although, without the module, they would remain inoperative).

OpenLDAP 2.5 [moved](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin25/guide.html#ppolicy%20overlay) the schema definitions into the overlay module itself (as is typical practice for OpenLDAP modules) and removed ppolicy.schema. For your entry to be accepted, you must now have ppolicy loaded so that it would provide the necessary definition of an 'pwdPolicy' object class.